# How to customize JSLint?

Tags: xml, configuration, coding-style, jslint

I would like to know if there's a way to customize JSLint in my XML configuration. For example:

- I don't want TABS AT ALL!! (<indent> option do not distinguishes between a 4 spaces tab)
- Only comments should have XX characters.
- Not using Hungarian notation.
- Use a custom indentation (sometimes X, and sometimes X+1)
- One true brace style (is this the <immed>>true</immed> option??)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's a two (or three) step process:

1. Fork [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint)
2. Update it to do what you want
3. (Optional) Publish your changes on Github for others to pull.

Now how to accomplish step #2?  That will depend -- you reference an XML file, which is, I assume, your deployment file (possibly for ANT?).  There are some changes you can make to [JSLints options](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) -- if they don't do it for you, then try making some modifications, and ask questions if you get stuck. :-)